# Spring Boot Service always null after @Autowire in JavaFX Controller Class

Tags: java, spring-boot, javafx, dependency-injection, autowired

I am currently developing an application that uses Spring Boot and JavaFX. I want to store email and password in H2 database. With a JUnit test I have already checked if the database is running and I have access to the Spring Boot repository. This works. However, I need to access the Spring Boot service from the JavaFX controller to be able to control the logic from the GUI and after I autowire the Spring Boot service in this class, a NullPointerException comes.

JavaFXController

```
@Component
@FxmlView("start.fxml")
@Service
public class JavaFXController {

    @FXML private Label startLabel;
    @FXML private Label settingsLabel;
    @FXML private TextField emailAmazonMerchOnDemand;
    @FXML private PasswordField passwordAmazonMerchOnDemand;

    private Stage stage;
    private Scene scene;

    @Autowired
    private AmazonMerchOnDemandService amazonMerchOnDemandService;

    @FXML
    public void openSettingsSceneFromStartScene() throws IOException {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("settings.fxml"));
        stage = (Stage)(startLabel.getScene().getWindow());
        scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    @FXML
    public void saveLogins() {
        String emailAmazon = emailAmazonMerchOnDemand.getText();
        String passwordAmazon = passwordAmazonMerchOnDemand.getText();
        AmazonMerchOnDemand amazonMerchOnDemandLogin = new AmazonMerchOnDemand();
        amazonMerchOnDemandLogin.setId(1L);
        amazonMerchOnDemandLogin.setEmail(emailAmazon);
        amazonMerchOnDemandLogin.setPassword(passwordAmazon);
        amazonMerchOnDemandService.saveLogin(amazonMerchOnDemandLogin);
    }
}
```

JavaFXApplication

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class JavaFXApplication extends Application {
    private ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public void init() throws Exception {
        String[] args = getParameters().getRaw().toArray(new String[0]);
        this.applicationContext = new SpringApplicationBuilder().sources(PrintOnDemandSellerViewApplication.class).run(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        URL xmlUrl = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("start.fxml");
        loader.setLocation(xmlUrl);
        loader.setController(applicationContext.getBean(JavaFXController.class));
        Parent root = loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() throws Exception {
        this.applicationContext.close();
        Platform.exit();
    }
}
```

AmazonMerchOnDemandService

```
@Service
@Component
public class AmazonMerchOnDemandService {

    public static WebDriver driver;
    private static int amountOfSales;

    @Autowired
    private AmazonMerchOnDemandRepository amazonMerchOnDemandRepository;

    public void saveLogin(AmazonMerchOnDemand amazonMerchOnDemand) {
        amazonMerchOnDemandRepository.save(amazonMerchOnDemand);
    }

    public void chromeDriverSetUp() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }

    public void login() {
        String email = amazonMerchOnDemandRepository.findById(1L).get().getEmail();
        System.out.println("Email: " + email);
        String password = amazonMerchOnDemandRepository.findById(1L).get().getPassword();
        System.out.println("Password: " + password);
}
}
```

AmazonMerchOnDemandRepository

```
@Repository
public interface AmazonMerchOnDemandRepository extends CrudRepository <AmazonMerchOnDemand, Long> {
}
```

PrintOnDemandSellerViewApplicationTests

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = JavaFXApplication.class)
class PrintOnDemandSellerViewApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private AmazonMerchOnDemandRepository amazonMerchOnDemandRepository;
    @Autowired
    private AmazonMerchOnDemandSampleData amazonMerchOnDemandSampleData;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setupData() {
        amazonMerchOnDemandSampleData.createAmazonMerchOnDemandLogin();
    }

    @Test
    public void testHasAmazonMerchOnDemandLoginRightPasswordAndRightEmail() {
        assertTrue(amazonMerchOnDemandRepository.existsById(1L));
        Optional<AmazonMerchOnDemand> amazonMerchOnDemandOptional = amazonMerchOnDemandRepository.findById(1L);
        assertFalse(amazonMerchOnDemandOptional.isEmpty());
        AmazonMerchOnDemand amazonMerchOnDemandLogin = amazonMerchOnDemandOptional.get();
        assertEquals("password", amazonMerchOnDemandLogin.getPassword());
        assertEquals("test@gmail.com", amazonMerchOnDemandLogin.getEmail());
    }

}
```

NullPointerException

```
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor37.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml@19/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:84)
    at javafx.fxml@19/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1854)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.printondemandsellerview.JavaFXController.saveLogins(JavaFXController.java:53)
    ... 40 more
```

I have tried several solutions from StackOverflow:

[Dependency Injection in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40539310/dependency-injection-and-javafx)
[Spring Data Autowire in FXML Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46654085/spring-data-autowire-in-fxml-controller-javafx)

Unfortunately, none of the solutions could help me. Do you have any other suggestions as to what the problem might be?

Comment: I notice you have two FXML files. Presumably `settings.fxml` has its own controller class, and presumably since you are not setting the controller or the controller factory when you load `settings.fxml`, that controller does not need to be managed by spring. Assuming all that is true and the null pointer exception is stemming from an action in `start.fxml`, I would check that 1. you do **not** have a `fx:controller` attribute in `start.fxml`, and 2. `applicationContext.getBean(JavaFXController.class)` is not returning null.

Comment: Also note that JavaFX controller classes in DI-managed applications (such as Spring) should have `prototype` scope. If you load the same FXML twice, you should have two controller instances.

Comment: Perhaps consider [javafx-weaver](https://github.com/rgielen/javafx-weaver), rather than a custom Spring integration.  I have never used the javafx-weaver library, so the link is not a recommendation, just something for you to investigate and evaluate independently.

Comment: I demonstrate wiring a service into a controller in [Adding Spring Dependency Injection in JavaFX (JPA Repo, Service)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57896435/1155209).  Perhaps take a look at that.

Comment: @James_D In the settings.fxml I also use the JavaFXController class as controller. In the start.fxml I have no fx:controller attribute. When I call applicationContext.getBean(JavaFXController.class), it does not return null. The null pointer exception occurs when I call the saveLogins() method in the GUI. There the class then accesses the repository for the first time. Because this is null, the null pointer exception occurs.

Comment: *"In the settings.fxml I also use the JavaFXController class as controller. "*. Don't do this. Each FXML should have its own controller class. Since you don't set the controller or controller factory when you load `settings.fxml`, the controller that is created when you load `settings.fxml` is not spring-managed, and so won't have any spring-injected fields initialized.