# How to get ApplicationContext in main function - Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, javafx

I want to combine two libraries - JavaFx and Spring Boot, thus I need to have an instance of `ApplicationContext` in my start() method in main class:

Main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class JavaFXandSpringBootTestApplication extends Application{

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext ctx;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(JavaFXandSpringBootTestApplication.class, args);
        launch();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxml/LogIn.fxml"));
        loader.setController(ctx.getBean(LogInController.class)); // HERE OCCURES ERROR
        Scene scene = new Scene((Parent)loader.load());
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

    }

}
```

Controller class:

```
@Component
public class LogInController {

}
```

As I have read the documentary `@SpringBootApplication` enables auto detect of Components and under the hood is also annotating the class with `@Configuration`.
So now, why am i reciving a NullPointerException in commended line? It's because that ctx isn't injected properly, but why? What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I can also add that there are many examples in other websites that perform this in the same way! (e.g https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/how-to-display-all-beans-loaded-by-spring-boot/)

Comment: How about taking a look at what the [`run`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication.html#run-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String...-) method returns... Also what is your `launch` method doing looks like this is a JavaFX application which doesn't actually use the `main` in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't inject the `ApplicationContext` (or anything else) into the `Application` instance on which `start()` is invoked: that instance of `Application` is created for you by JavaFX, not by Spring. Since it's not a spring-managed object, there is no mechanism for Spring to inject anything into it.

Move the call to `SpringApplication.run()` to the `init()` method, where you can simply assign the context directly. Also, imho a better way to let the controllers be Spring-managed is to tell the `FXMLLoader` to create controllers via Spring, which you can do with a controller factory. See [Dependency Injection and JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40539310/dependency-injection-and-javafx).

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class JavaFXandSpringBootTestApplication extends Application{

    private ApplicationContext ctx;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void init() {
        String[] args = getParameters().getRaw().toArray(new String[0]);
        ctx = SpringApplication.run(JavaFXandSpringBootTestApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxml/LogIn.fxml"));
        loader.setControllerFactory(ctx::getBean); 
        // or, if you prefer,
        // loader.setController(ctx.getBean(LoginController.class));
        // though the controller factory approach lets you use `fx:controller` as usual.
        Scene scene = new Scene((Parent)loader.load());
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

    }

}
```